# AMPscript ExactTarget: can I find out what's the first letter / number of a dynamic content?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

How can I find out what's the first letter of a dynamic piece of content using AMPscript? Is there a function for that?

e.g.
`Var @content, @new_content
Set @content = [CONTENT]
IF @content STARTS WITH 'a' THEN
SET @new_content = 'blah blah'`

Thanks,
VD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need the [SubString()](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/#Substring) function.

```
%%[

if not empty(@content) and substring(@content,1,1) == 'a' then
  set @new_content = "blah blah"
endif

]%%
```

You should bookmark the [AMPScript functions page](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_functions/).

Comment: Thanks Adam, actually I ended up using a Substring right after posting the question :)